# unable to create ref in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput

I want to set focus on next `TextInput` using `createRef()`. I am getting error in `createRef()`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
            this.r2Ref = React.createRef();
            this.r3Ref = React.createRef();
            this.r4Ref = React.createRef();
            this.r5Ref = React.createRef();
    }

render() {
        return (
            <View style={SetStyle.settingsCont}>
            <ScrollView>

                <View style={SetStyle.contRate}>

                    <View style={SetStyle.rView}>
                        <Text style={SetStyle.rText}>Rate1</Text>
                        <TextInput style={SetStyle.rInput} keyboardType='numeric'
                            returnKeyType="next" onSubmitEditing={() => this.refs.r2Ref.focus()}></TextInput>
                    </View>
                    <View style={SetStyle.rView}>
                        <Text style={SetStyle.rText}>Rate2</Text>
                        <TextInput style={SetStyle.rInput} keyboardType='numeric'
                            ref={r2Ref => this.r2Ref = r2Ref}
                            returnKeyType="next" onSubimitEditing={() => this.refs.r3Ref.focus()}></TextInput>
                    </View>
                    <View style={SetStyle.rView}>
                        <Text style={SetStyle.rText}>Rate3</Text>
                        <TextInput style={SetStyle.rInput} keyboardType='numeric'
                        ref={r3Ref => this.r3Ref = r3Ref}
                        returnKeyType="next" onSubmitEditing={() => this.refs.r4Ref.focus()}></TextInput>
                    </View>
                    <View style={SetStyle.rView}>
                        <Text style={SetStyle.rText}>Rate4</Text>
                        <TextInput style={SetStyle.rInput} keyboardType='numeric'
                            ref={r4Ref => this.r4Ref = r4Ref}
                            returnKeyType="next" onSubmitEditing={() => this.refs.r5Ref.focus()}></TextInput>
                    </View>
                    <View style={SetStyle.rView}>
                        <Text style={SetStyle.rText}>Rate5</Text>
                        <TextInput style={SetStyle.rInput} keyboardType='numeric'
                            ref={r5Ref => this.r5Ref = r5Ref}></TextInput>
                    </View>
                </View>

            </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I am getting following error :

> Undefined is not an object (evaluating this2.refs.r2Refs.focus)

Comment: Can you please add the Error message you are getting

Comment: Also, you shouldn't define refs in state. define them as class variables.

Comment: I defined refs out of state also. But then also I am getting error

Comment: Rather than onSubmitEditing={() => this.refs.r2Ref.focus()} . did you tried like below onSubmitEditing={() => this.r2Ref.current.focus()}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing createRef() from the constructor and removing `ref` from  `onSubmitEditing`

Then I wrote the following way:

```
<TextInput ref={r2Ref => this.r2Ref = r2Ref}></TextInput>
```

and used it the following way:

```
<TextInput onSubmitEditing={() => this.r2Ref.focus()}></TextInput>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are mixing [Callback Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) with the [createRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs) API.
Also you are accessing them wrong. Once you have defined them as variables, you need to use said variables instead.

What you need to do is something like:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  r2Ref = React.createRef();

  render() {
    return <Input name="r2" ref={this.r2Ref} />
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Initialise  
this.fieldOne = React.createRef();


<TextInput style = {styles.input}
               underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
               placeholder = "Email"
               ref={this.fieldOne}
               onChangeText = {this.xxxxx} />

//To set focus
this.fieldOne.current.focus();
```

Above code is working for me. Hope, it will hep someone

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are using Type Script. I have achieved with below code for implementing OTP.

```
 import {
   SafeAreaView,
   StyleSheet,
   Text,
   View,
   TouchableOpacity,
   TextInput
 } from 'react-native';

class OtpScreen extends React.Component<IProps, State> {

  input1Ref: React.RefObject<TextInput>;
  input2Ref : React.RefObject<TextInput>;
  input3Ref : React.RefObject<TextInput>;
  input4Ref : React.RefObject<TextInput>;
  input5Ref : React.RefObject<TextInput>;
  input6Ref : React.RefObject<TextInput>;

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.input1Ref = React.createRef();
    this.input2Ref = React.createRef();
    this.input3Ref = React.createRef();
    this.input4Ref = React.createRef();
    this.input5Ref = React.createRef();
    this.input6Ref = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
     return (
      <SafeAreaView style={Styles.container}>
        <View style={Styles.otpInputContainer}>
        <InputField
          nameRef={this.input1Ref}
          value={this.state.otpFirstNumber}
          onChangeText={(value: any) => {
            this.setState({ otpFirstNumber: value });
            this.input2Ref.current?.focus()
          }}
        />
        <InputField
          nameRef={this.input2Ref}
          value={this.state.otpSecondNumber}
          onChangeText={(value: any) => {
            this.setState({ otpSecondNumber: value });
            this.input3Ref.current?.focus()
          }}
        />
        <InputField
          nameRef={this.input3Ref}
          value={this.state.otpThirdNumber}
          onChangeText={(value: any) => {
            this.setState({ otpThirdNumber: value });
            this.input4Ref.current?.focus()
          }}            />
        <InputField
          nameRef={this.input4Ref}
          value={this.state.otpFourthNumber}
          onChangeText={(value: any) => {
            this.setState({ otpFourthNumber: value });
            this.input5Ref.current?.focus()
          }}          
            />
        <InputField
          nameRef={this.input5Ref}
          value={this.state.otpFifthNumber}
          onChangeText={(value: any) => {
            this.setState({ otpFifthNumber: value });
            this.input6Ref.current?.focus()
          }}               />
        <InputField
          nameRef={this.input6Ref}
          value={this.state.otpFifthNumber}
          onChangeText={(number: number) => this.inputNumber(number, 6)}
        />
       </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
```